# How to iterate in Databricks to read hundreds of files stored in different subdirectories in a Data Lake?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have to read hundreds of avro files in Databricks from an Azure Data Lake Gen2, extract data from the Body field inside every file, and concatenate all the extracted data in a unique dataframe. The point is that all avro files to read are **stored in different subdirectories** in the lake, following the pattern:

root/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/mm/ss.avro

This forces me to loop the ingestion and selection of data. I'm using this Python code, in which list_avro_files is the list of paths to all files:

```
list_data = []

for file_avro in list_avro_files:
  df = spark.read.format('avro').load(file_avro)
  data1 = spark.read.json(df.select(df.Body.cast('string')).rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]))
  list_data.append(data1)

data = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, list_data)
```

Is there any way to do this more efficiently? How can I parallelize/speed up this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your `list_avro_files` can be expressed through standard wildcard syntax, you can probably use Spark's own ability to parallelize read operation. All you'd need is to specify a **`basepath`** and a filename pattern for your avro files:

```
scala> var df = spark.read
                 .option("basepath","/user/hive/warehouse/root")
                 .format("avro")
                 .load("/user/hive/warehouse/root/*/*/*/*.avro")
```

And, in case you find that you need to know exactly which file any given row came from, use `input_file_name()` built-in function to enrich your dataframe:

```
scala> df = df.withColumn("source",input_file_name())
```